# Get Hive partition schemas

Tags: hive

As far as I understand Hive keeps track of schema for all partitions, handling schema evolution.

Is there any way to get schema for particular partition? For example, if I want to compare schema for some old partition with the latest one.

Comment: some more details about the question will help - like what you want here - historical data like how partitions growing? You can see current state using `show partitions table_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Show extended command does give you a bunch of information around the partition columns and its types, probably you could use those.

```
SHOW TABLE EXTENDED [IN|FROM database_name] LIKE 'identifier_with_wildcards' [PARTITION(partition_spec)];
```

Reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowTable/PartitionExtended